# How to create a meta-package that automatically installs other packages?

Tags: package-management, dpkg, packaging, metapackages, equivs

I'd like to be able to create a package that doesnt contain any code or programs itself, but instead installs other packages that exist in the repositories onto a computer, sort of how the `ubuntu-restricted-extras` package does?

Answer (score 55, accepted):

A meta-package like this can be created with a tool called `equivs` [image] which will create a package with just dependency information.

First, create a directory:

```
mkdir my-metapackage
cd my-metapackage/
```

Now run the program:

```
equivs-control ns-control
```

It will create a file called `ns-control`, open this file with your text editor. 
The control file that you generate should have its `Depends` or `Recommends` lines modified to depend on the packages that you want installed:

```
Section: misc
Priority: optional
Standards-Version: 3.9.1

Package: my-metapackage
Version: 1.0   
Depends: openssh-server, gedit
Description: This package installes an ssh server and a text editor
 The Long description of this package ends with a newline!
```

(Just an example, you should include more information)

And finally, build the package by running

```
equivs-build ns-control
```

Your package is located at `my-metapackage/my-metapackage_1.0_all.deb`.

If you wish to also create a source package, the `--full` option can be passed to `equivs-build`, e.g. `equivs-build --full ns-control`. This will use debuild & also create .dsc & .tar.gz files.

To create a source .changes file that you can upload to a PPA, extract & build the source package with

```
dpkg-source -x my-metapackage_1.0.dsc
cd my-metapackage-1.0
debuild -S
```

If the Maintainer that you set in ns-control matches your GPG key, it should build & sign the my-metapackage_1.0_source.changes file for you to dput to your PPA

Comment: Thanks much.  I will most likely test this later, but so far, the instructions worked.  :)

Comment: It works perfectly!

Comment: Thanks for the answer, ajmitch, but just because reasons, I"m going to point out that if you have a `~/.devscripts` file and specifically define a different GPG key to use in the devscripts file, it will OVERRIDE the dpkg/debuild process and have it use the specific GPG key specified in `.devscripts`.  Just as a noteworthy point for the last sentence in your answer.

Comment: I noticed that putting the packages under `Depends:` makes installation good if and only if packages are there; it doesn't installs them if they're not on my machine. To install them, I used `Provides` instead and it works like a charm. See my code (just changed it): https://github.com/palladius/debian-packages/blob/master/palladius-ubuntu-desktop/ns-control