# GUI for ubuntu server: xfce or xubuntu-desktop

Tags: server, xubuntu, gui, xfce

I would like to install a desktop environment on my Ubuntu server 12.04. I like xubuntu-desktop as it is a light-weight one. But I'm confused between xubuntu-desktop and xfce. Can anyone tell me what difference between the two following commands:

```
sudo apt-get install --no-install-recommends xubuntu-desktop
```

and

```
sudo apt-get install xfce
```

Comment: you can always install a desktop and then just remove it if you don't like it...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Both are metapackages but xubuntu-desktop is a metapackage for [much more stuff](http://packages.ubuntu.com/precise/xubuntu-desktop) than [the other one](http://packages.ubuntu.com/precise/xfce4) that is just for the desktop environment, xorg and few minor things.
You can read about the difference between a package and a metapackage [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/66257/what-is-the-difference-between-a-meta-package-and-a-package).
In short metapackage does not contain anything else than references and what matters is what metapackage refers to (metapackage claims to depend on them and asks that list to be installed).

So I guess your first option would not install anything. If you really want the minimal solution then go with xfce for which the correct command would be:

```
sudo apt-get install xfce4
```

Just add anything else one by one according to your needs. Also if you have xfce4 installed you can always expand your install with xubuntu-desktop that would just add lots of stuff.

You could also consider using [Webmin](http://www.webmin.com/) or [Zentyal](https://help.ubuntu.com/12.04/serverguide/zentyal.html) for web based server management.

Answer (score 6):

First, `sudo apt-get install xfce` returns:

```
E: Unable to locate package xfce
```

If you run `apt-cache search xfce` you'll get a longish list that includes

```
xfce4 - Meta-package for the Xfce Lightweight Desktop Environment
```

and

```
xfdesktop4 - xfce desktop background, icons and root menu manager
```

I suspect you may want either `xfce4` or `xfdesktop4` instead of `xubuntu-desktop`.

Next, you can look at the description for both `xfce4` and `xfdesktop4` using:

```
apt-cache show xfce4
```

and

```
apt-cache show xfdesktop4
```

I'm pasting part of the output for `apt-cache show xfce4` below:

> Description-en: Meta-package for the Xfce Lightweight Desktop Environment
>    Xfce is a lightweight desktop environment for unix-like operating systems.
>    It aims to be fast and lightweight, while still being visually appealing and
>    easy to use.  Designed for productivity, it loads and executes applications
>    fast, while conserving system resources.
>
> This package is a metapackage;  it depends on the core packages of the
>    Xfce4 desktop environment and recommends some extra Xfce4 packages.  If you
>    intend to use Xfce4 and want the full experience then installing this
>    package and the packages it Recommends is a great place to start.
>    If you just want to pick and choose the core components then feel free to
>    remove this package.

Next, you can run the following commands:

```
sudo apt-get install -s xfce4
```

and

```
sudo apt-get install -s xfdesktop4
```

Then inspect the output and judge for yourself. Nothing will actually be installed because the `-s` ensures it's just a simulation.
My feeling is that you should install `xfce4` and see if you're satisfied.

Comment: sorry, I mean "sudo apt-get install xfce4"

Answer (score 1):

Both xfce4 and xubuntu-desktop are meta packages and you can find out what files any package contains,  what packages are required, what packages are recommended, what packages are suggested and what if any packages it conflicts with by searching from here.

http://packages.ubuntu.com/

If you compare the pages returned for [xfce4](http://packages.ubuntu.com/raring/xfce4) and [xubuntu-desktop](http://packages.ubuntu.com/raring/xubuntu-desktop) you will see that xubuntu-desktop depends on most of the same packages as xfce4 and a lot more besides.

```
sudo apt-get install xfce4
```

Will install a lot less than

```
sudo apt-get install --no-install-recommends xubuntu-desktop
```