# Most of the UI elements are missed (Xubuntu or XFCE4 over Ubuntu Server on VirtualBox)

Tags: xubuntu, virtualbox, xfce, gui

I installed Ubuntu in a virtual machine using the official mini.iso image and decided to try Xubuntu with the following command:

```
sudo apt-get install --no-install-recommends xubuntu-desktop
```

But what I got you can see here:

[image]

No icons (though some icons are ok), wallpaper, tray.

The same happens when if I install xfce4. I reinstalled Ubuntu from mini.iso and tried this:

```
sudo apt-get install xfce4
```

But there are still no icons (in the same places). And desktop icons look horrible.

[image]

Please help me to get a normal UI. I really don't want to install Ubuntu with a huge package of unnecessary software.

Comment: Looks like you need xfce4, rather then xubuntu-desktop ~ possible duplicate of [GUI for ubuntu server: xfce or xubuntu-desktop](http://askubuntu.com/questions/305646/gui-for-ubuntu-server-xfce-or-xubuntu-desktop) ...and sure, it's wrong  for you only.

Comment: Have just tried xfce4, it didn't help. The problem is like with Xubuntu. The same icons are missed and the rest of them look really bad.

Answer (score 0):

Dealt with this recently. The following fixed it for me:

```
sudo apt-get install gnome-icon-theme-full tango-icon-theme
```

Answer (score 0):

Try running:

```
sudo apt-get install xubuntu-icon-theme
```