# Can I remove file-roller without removing ubuntu-desktop?

Tags: 12.04, unity, dependencies

I am running Ubuntu 12.04. When I try to remove `file-roller` (the built-in "Archive Manager" app) from my system as I now use `ark` (using Synaptic Package Manager), it asks me to also remove `ubuntu-desktop` (which I assume is the Unity DE).

I don't want to uninstall Unity from my system, so how do I go about removing this, whilst keeping Unity installed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can safely remove `ubuntu-desktop` as it is a meta-package, and does not provide any actual content. It only depends/recommends other packages. Removing it will not remove Unity or other features.

See also: [What is the difference between a meta-package and a package?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/66257/what-is-the-difference-between-a-meta-package-and-a-package)

Comment: Thanks for this! I've marked as final answer (though haven't got round to booting into Ubuntu yet to do this)

Answer (score 0):

Since `ubuntu-desktop`'s package dependency on `file-roller` is hard (it Depends, as opposed to Recommends or Suggests), you cannot uninstall `file-roller` without uninstalling `ubuntu-desktop`.

On the other hand, `ubuntu-desktop` is a meta-package, so you could achieve the equivalent by installing all packages it depends on, except `file-roller`, though I doubt that this is worth the effort.

Why not keep both installed?