# Different versions of Wine

Tags: wine, playonlinux

Sorry if this is a duplicate, but can you guys please help me out?

I noticed that there are four different "Wine" programs in the Ubuntu Software Centre.

"Microsoft Windows Compatability Layer (meta-package)"

"Q4Wine"

"Wine Windows Program Loader"

"Play On Linux"

I just installed all four.

I read that Play on Linux is the best one. Was it unnecesarry to install all four? Are they going to interfere with each other? Do I need to uninstall some of them, or can I just keep all four, and use the one I like? Any other tips?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Microsoft Windows Compatibility Layer ([meta-package](https://askubuntu.com/questions/66257/what-is-the-difference-between-a-meta-package-and-a-package))"

Is a meta package, it contains all the meta data (info on required libs etc) for installing wine on your distribution.

"[Wine Windows Program Loader](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Wine)"

This is `wine` program itself.

"[Q4wine](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/precise/q4wine/)"

Q4Wine will help you manage wine prefixes and installed applications, a front end for `wine` configuration.

"[Play on Linux](https://www.playonlinux.com/en/)"

Again this is a front end for `wine` that focuses more on installing games.

"Was it unnecessary to install all four? Are they going to interfere with each other?"

Well `play on linux` and `Q4wine` require `wine` of course and both are useful in there own way, so no worries there, and the meta package simply points to and installs `wine` and any other requirements (probably Q4wine too), so no issues there. the frontends aren't required but are great for beginners.

Comment: Alright, great, thanks! I'll just keep them all, then. I noticed that PlayOnLinux starts downloading Wine again when trying to install a .exe file. I suppose it's customizing to make it work or something.

Comment: Play on Linux will install multiple versions of `wine`, if you have ever used a games console emulator, you will know some games work best on some versions of the emulator, same with `wine`, some versions are developed for specific programs etc. If this helped you please press the accept button on the left so others can easily find it.

Answer (score 1):

This is entirely down to preference, there are also versions of it which are more "User friendly" and offer graphic interfaces to automate everything but cost money to use. Personally I just use Wine provided by

`sudo apt-get install wine`

never had issues with it, but some people prefer the alternatives.