# apt-get install package without version number

Tags: apt

When you do `apt-get install` a package, there are many items listed. For example, `sudo apt-get install emacs` and press `tab`,  you receive `emacs`, `emacs23`, `emacs24`...... What does the one without version number represent? The latest stable version?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The numbers after `emacs` are the version numbers of `emacs`.

If you do not want to be bothered with the version number and want to install the latest version, just go for `emacs`, it is a meta package that always depends on the latest version of `emacs` found on the `main` repository.

The older versions are found on the `universe` repository (and/or perhaps on some other repositories too).

In a nutshell, you can do:

```
sudo apt-get install emacs
```

to install the latest version.

---

Also see:  [What is the difference between a meta-package and a package?](https://askubuntu.com/q/66257/216503)

Comment: More details on what a "meta package" is, or the differences between the repositories you mentioned will get this a +1 from me. I feel like the question is more about package installation in general than about emacs specifically.

Comment: @MichaelHoffmann check my edits