# Running a program that is installed via aptitude

Tags: apt, execute-command

After a installation via aptitude, how does one actually run the program? (via nautilus or even terminal)

for example, i'm now trying to use a program called pulseview. 
for this i installed a package called sigrok using `sudo apt-get install sigrok`

sigrok is already in the repository. The sigrok package also contains pulseview. I believe sigrok is the CLI and pulseview the GUI, but that assumption could be wrong.

The installation worked perfectly, but how do I now run the program?

## What I have tried

- I first searched for the application, but didn't find it. I also tried to find it via Software Centre but no luck there :(
- I then tried to see if installation actually worked by doing the same again. 
  It informed me that the latest version was already installed.
  then i thought i might need to install pulseview seperately, via aptitude. but also on that i got informed that the latest version was already installed.
- So tried (sudo) ./sigrok and pulseview but no such file or directory (as one would expect).

Sorry to ask someting, which will probably be so obvious, but when I search for topics the explanation stops after the install line and no added info on how to run it. I actually thought I had made a similar topic before, but even in that topic there was no answer on this part.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: thanks so much!.. sigrok didn't work, but pulseview did! 
again thanks!

Comment: The command-line interface is actually named `sigrok-cli`. Sorry about that.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Sigrok is a [metapackage](https://askubuntu.com/q/66257/457562) which pulls in pulseview, the GUI (as you thought), and sigrok-cli, the command-line interface to sigrok. To run the GUI, (located in `/usr/bin/pulseview`) it should suffice to run `pulseview` (not `./pulseview`) because `/usr/bin` is on your [search path](https://www.decf.berkeley.edu/help/unix/searchpath.html).

Comment: oke, that is usefull to understand, something i then clearly yet don't understand is the exact meaning of ./

Comment: `./command` runs the binary file named `command` in your [current working directory](http://www.linfo.org/current_directory.html).

Comment: additionally something i don't understend, is why do i NOW find pulseview in a search under  applications while it wasn't there before. 
I have the feeling (and had this before) i need to run a program at least once before it ends up in a search in applications, which would be strange. do i need to restart nautilus or something after an install to find te program?

Comment: I doubt it. It showed up right away for me. Either it was a glitch or it was in the process of adding it to the menu.

Comment: oke. that is thus something i understoon completely inverse.. 
my thought was that: 
"program name" would look locally, and ./program name in the standard search path.

Comment: well, that is strange then.. as i said, i have had this problem before, without doubt (and i doubt myself quickly, but not on this) and this glitch would have been then there in several distribution installations.  none the less. i have learned a lot from you and am happy i have this digitally available, for if i would ever forget, but i don't think that will happen ;) again. many thanks for your time and input!

Comment: sorry i thought i already did :/, definately helpfull and very deserved checkmark ;), and as i did afterwards i realise that only one of the 2 aswers an be checkmarked, as i check mark the other it disappears from the first so thats why i tought i already did so. made sure it stayed on your though ;)

Answer (score 3):

As [Nonny Moose](https://askubuntu.com/users/457562/nonny-moose) commented, when you install a new package via apt or aptitude, unless you deliberately install the package elsewhere, it will install to the default location (`/usr/bin` and `/usr/local/bin` are quite common). This path is included in what's called your PATH.

When you run a command from your terminal, it will first check your PATH for what you are looking for. If you specify a path (as you were doing with `./my_file`), it means "Look in this directory and run this file".

As you can see in this example, I asked my system to tell me where exactly it would find sigrok if I asked, to which it tells me where it looked and failed to find it (because I don't have it installed).

```
$ ~: which sigrok
/usr/bin/which: no sigrok in (/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/bin:/usr/sbin:/bin:/sbin:/home/user/bin)
```