# What's the Difference between NVIDIA driver metapackage and NVIDIA binary driver?

Tags: nvidia, 18.04

Ubuntu 18.04 LTS gives me three choices for my GeForce GT730 card.

1. Noveau (opensource)
2. NVIDIA driver metapackage / nvidia-driver-390 (closedsource, tested)
3. NVIDIA binary driver - version 340.106 / nvidia-340 (closedsource)

I know that nvidia driver is better for gaming, but which one ? **"Driver metapackage" or "binary driver", What's the difference ? What does it mean "metapackage" in this case ?** Thank you.

Comment: Your question may be answered here: https://askubuntu.com/q/61396/57576

Comment: It's really old question and it does not answers me what is **metapackage** and why it is better or worse than binary driver (both proprietary and both from nvidia). What's the meaning of metapackage in this situation ?

Comment: Related: https://askubuntu.com/questions/66257/what-is-the-difference-between-a-meta-package-and-a-package

Comment: Great question. I can't believe there is not an official answer to this.