# Which mysql-server is my server using?

Tags: server, mysql, amazon-ec2

I have ubuntu 14.04 on my aws ec2 instance. I ran following command to find out the mysql-server installations and I got multiple results :

```
dpkg --get-selections | grep mysql
```

[image]

Now I would like to remove the one's not in use, so my question is how to find out which one is in use?

***Noob Alert***

Comment: Welcome to [ubuntu.se]! Please do not [post screenshots of the terminal](https://meta.askubuntu.com/q/8713/250300). Paste the text directly to your question and apply [code formatting](https://askubuntu.com/editing-help#code).

Comment: There are no duplicates in your setup nothing that you can remove and nothing to worry about.

Comment: related: https://askubuntu.com/questions/66257/what-is-the-difference-between-a-meta-package-and-a-package and https://askubuntu.com/questions/1069744/what-is-the-difference-between-php-and-php7-2-packages

Comment: You are using `5.5` and for the `mysql-server` that's a meta package, please don't remove them