# How do I remove Confluent CLI completely?

Tags: command-line, apt, package-management, software-uninstall

I used the following commands to install Confluent CLI to my Ubuntu system following [the steps that are mentioned here](https://docs.confluent.io/current/installation/installing_cp/deb-ubuntu.html).

I executed the following commands consecutively:

```bash
wget -qO - https://packages.confluent.io/deb/3.3/archive.key | sudo apt-key add -
sudo add-apt-repository "deb [arch=amd64] https://packages.confluent.io/deb/3.3 stable main"

sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install confluent-platform-oss-2.11
```

Now in order to remove, I executed the following command:

```bash
sudo apt-get remove confluent-platform-oss-2.11
```

Also, I executed:

```bash
sudo add-apt-repository --remove "deb [arch=amd64] https://packages.confluent.io/deb/3.3 stable main"
```

But they did not help. Still when I type `confluent` in the terminal the available options are coming up and I am able to execute them. So how can I completely remove it from my system?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TL;DR: *Running `sudo apt --purge autoremove` should work to complete the uninstallation.*

#### Use the `autoremove` action to uninstall the remaining dependencies.

You've uninstalled the `confluent-platform-oss-2.11` package, but this is a [metapackage](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/MetaPackages), which [doesn't itself provide any software](https://askubuntu.com/questions/66257/what-is-the-difference-between-a-meta-package-and-a-package).<sup>1</sup> Installing it caused several other packages to be installed, which themselves provide the software. Removing `confluent-platform-oss-2.11` causes those other packages to be *eligible* for automatic removal, but it doesn't actually remove them. To remove them now, it should be sufficient to run:

```
sudo apt autoremove
```

Or, if you *also* want to remove systemwide configuration files associated with the software, you can run this command *instead*:

```
sudo apt --purge autoremove
```

In either case, `apt` will show you what packages will be removed and ask you if you want that done.

You are still able to run the `confluent` command because that command is provided by the `confluent-cli` package,<sup>2</sup> which installing `confluent-platform-oss-2.11` caused to be installed. `confluent-cli` is, accordingly, one of the packages that `autoremove` will uninstall.

---

#### If you need (or want) to investigate further...

This section is in case you want to know more, or for the fairly infrequent situation where the `autoremove` action is insufficient.

When you originally installed `confluent-platform-oss-2.11`, the output of `apt-get` would have included something like this:

```
The following additional packages will be installed:
  confluent-camus confluent-cli confluent-common confluent-kafka-2.11 confluent-kafka-connect-elasticsearch
  confluent-kafka-connect-hdfs confluent-kafka-connect-jdbc confluent-kafka-connect-s3
  confluent-kafka-connect-storage-common confluent-kafka-rest confluent-rest-utils confluent-schema-registry
```

It is rare that you would have to remove those packages manually, though. Every package installed on your system is marked as manually or automatically installed. You specifically asked for `confluent-platform-oss-2.11` to be installed, so it was marked as manually installed. Packages that are installed only because other packages depend on them, and that you never subsequently attempt to install by name, are marked as automatically installed. The `autoremove` action (passed to `apt` or `apt-get`) removes automatically installed packages that are no longer depended on by any currently installed packages.

If `autoremove` didn't remove everything you expected, you can try removing packages manually. First, unless you know specifically what packages were installed, you should inspect the logs to check, in case it's not the same as what I showed above. The most useful logs are usually `/var/log/apt/history.log` and `/var/log/apt/term.log`. You can try uninstalling packages with `sudo apt remove ...` or `sudo apt purge ...` (or the corresponding commands with `apt-get`, if you prefer). If you do, you may be asked if you want to proceed. *Look at the list of packages carefully.* If `autoremove` didn't work, there may be something else depending on the packages. The `remove` action will remove them nonetheless, and *also* remove whatever depends on them!<sup>3</sup>

---

#### Notes

<sup>**1**</sup> I had guessed that this was so; I then confirmed it by inspecting the output of `dpkg-query -L confluent-platform-oss-2.11` on a system on which `confluent-platform-oss-2.11` was installed.

<sup>**2**</sup> Running `type confluent` to find out where `confluent` is, followed by `dpkg -S /usr/bin/confluent` to find out what package provides it, reveals this.

<sup>**3**</sup> The real story of dependency resolution is more complex, in general, than I've been letting on, because [there is more than one strength of dependency](https://www.debian.org/doc/debian-policy/ch-relationships.html#binary-dependencies-depends-recommends-suggests-enhances-pre-depends). It is sometimes possible to install package A, causing package B to be installed automatically, then remove package B *without* package A having to be removed. However, in your case, the packages that remain installed were installed because the metapackage has a strict "Depends" relationship to them, and it's unlikely anything else has has declared any kind of dependency on them.

Comment: Excellent answer! It worked for me.