# How to remove packages with unknown names

Tags: apt, package-management, uninstall

I made the grave mistake of running the command `sudo apt-get install -y games-minesweeper` thinking it would only install one game. It ended up installing like 30 or so games:

[image: installed games]

The problem is i can't uninstall these packages since they don't show up in the Ubuntu software app, and running:

`sudo apt-get remove games-minesweeper`

only returns:

`Package 'games-minesweeper' is not installed, so not removed`

I've also tried to run `sudo apt-get remove <AppName>` and it hasn't found any of the games' packages by the name of the application.

I've tried to also run `sudo apt-get remove <Debian Package ID>` and it hasn't found any of the games' packages by that either.

How do i uninstall these packages, or find out their package name? so i can run `sudo apt-get remove`

Comment: Look in `/var/log/apt/history.log` to find out what exactly was installed.

Comment: Welcome, [this will shed some light about what is happening](https://askubuntu.com/questions/66257/what-is-the-difference-between-a-meta-package-and-a-package).

Comment: @Jos Thanks, I've removed all of the packages that got installed when i ran the command

Comment: @schrodigerscatcuriosity Thank you, i was not aware of this concept and it would have helped prevent this.

Answer (score 0):

You have to locate their package names by using commands like

```
dpkg -S $(grep -r Penguins --include=*.desktop /usr/ 2> /dev/null --files-with-matches)
```

where `grep -r Penguins --include=*.desktop /usr/ 2> /dev/null --files-with-matches` running recursive search for *`Penguins`* in `/usr` folder and list the names of found `*.desktop` files. Then `dpkg -S …` finds corresponding package names for found files.

Penguins… [came](https://codesearch.debian.net/search?q=Penguin+Thornq&literal=1) [from](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=focal&arch=amd64&mode=filename&searchon=contents&keywords=penguin%20thornq) `ace-of-penguins` package. Remove them with

```
sudo apt-get remove ace-of-penguins
```

Comment: I agree with this method, but in my specific situation it was more effective to check `/var/log/apt/history.log` as @Jos mentioned and see what specific packages were installed with the command i ran and remove them.