# Downloading a specific version of google-chrome-stable from dl.google.com

Tags: google-chrome, downloads, versions, wget

Based on Sandi's response in the post on the link below, is there a way I can see all the versions that are available whether it is CentOS,Ubuntu, etc? For example if I'm looking for a specific version? Asking since I'm not able to navigate to the subfolders in dl.google.com. I just get a 404 Not Found error?

> You can download the latest version of Google Chrome from their official > website. For this, you can use the command-line with wget:

> wget https://dl.google.com/linux/direct/google-chrome-stable_current_amd64.deb

[Help with installing the Chrome web browser (22.04.2 LTS)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1461513/help-with-installing-the-chrome-web-browser-22-04-2-lts/1508301?noredirect=1#comment2646448_1508301)

Comment: Possibly related: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1495456/how-to-check-available-versions-in-google-debian-repository

Comment: This is a question for Google, not Ask Ubuntu, as we can't control what is or isn't visible on Google's site.