# Ignoring forcefully installed package?

Tags: package-management, apt, dpkg, amarok

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to create a meta-package that automatically installs other packages?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/33413/how-to-create-a-meta-package-that-automatically-installs-other-packages)

So I installed the good, old amarok14 package on Ubuntu 11.10 (Because there still isn't a music player that is as good as this age old player)

However: I had to install it using dpkg, making it ignoring the libmtp8 package (using `--ignore-depends=libmtp8`).

It runs beautifully, but whenever I want to install anything else (using apt-get, aptitude, synaptic, ...) it always wants me to REMOVE amarok14 first.

What can I do about this?

Comment: You fake it with a package that pretends to provide the right package. There are a few questions about this on the site already and I've marked this as a duplicate of what I consider to be the best one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had it removed using patget autoremove and cannot reinstall it due to dependencies issues :(
Your idea is good but I do not want to spend more time only for installing a program, unless someone finds a way to install it without messing up anything else.

I am still "glued" to AmaroK 1.4, but I recently tested out other players. My current choice (till I have tested some more) is Guayadeque. You should give it a try, if not already done. Last version seems stable and has all the features I liked on good old AmaroK.

I also made a comparison: http://socialcompare.com/en/comparison/linux-open-source-audio-players