# Am I permitted to create custom metapackages in PPAs?

Tags: ppa, metapackages

In my university, we want to create Metapackages to provide all the software used in the differents careers, and signatures.

¿We can do this? I ask because recently I read this:

"Note: We will not accept uploads of packages that are unmodified from their original source in Ubuntu or Debian, only packages that include your own changes. We ask that people include useful changelogs for each package so that users and other developers can understand what new features they are exploring in their work. Read the PPA Terms of Use for more information."

https://help.launchpad.net/Packaging/PPA/Uploading

Basicly we don't want to change the source code of the package, we only want to do a "compilation".

Comment: What do you mean by "metapackage" exactly? A "metapackage" typically means an empty package which only depends on other packages, and would thus be something you must provide your own changes for, as you must create the packaging, and specify the dependencies. It would have no source code in itself directly.

Comment: Exactly. And that is my question... According to the PPA policy, we can do that?

Comment: for how, see http://askubuntu.com/questions/33413/how-to-create-a-meta-package-that-automatically-installs-other-packages

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can upload a metapackage to a PPA on Launchpad, yes. As a metapackage contains no actual source code, and only results in an empty binary package (or multiple empty binary packages), that only depend on other packages, you must upload a source package which contains your own modifications, as you are creating the source package and specifying what the metapackage names are, what they depend on, and the other relevant metadata.