# Remote package installation over LAN

Tags: networking, system-installation, package-management, repository, localrepository

I am trying to work on a project where i am supposed to install softwares and packages on one system and it should replicate on other systems connected on LAN. 
How can i proceed with this?
I was thinking of creating a server with local ppa repository with all packages to be included. Can this be done?
Or is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

Here is what I would do:

Create a launchpad account.

Sign the Ubuntu Code of Conduct.

Make a PPA.

Write a metapackage that depends on all the packages you want to install. Every time you install a package, update the PPA.

You can learn how to write a metapackage [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/33417/420786).

Add the PPA to all computers you want to update.

Run:

```
sudo apt-get install yourmetapackage
```

When you change the PPA:

```
sudo apt-get upgrade
```