# How can I remove AbiWord?

Tags: lubuntu, lightdm, lxde, cinnamon, abiword

I've just installed Lubuntu, and then I threw Cinnamon on top of it. Every time I log into *any* session: gnome, cinnamon, lxde, `abiword` opens immediately, as if I had told it to.

I'm not a fan of this in the least, but even more annoying is this:

```
$ apt purge abiword
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
The following packages will be REMOVED:
  abiword* lubuntu-desktop*
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 2 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
After this operation, 5,027 kB disk space will be freed.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] ^C
$ apt remove abiword
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
The following packages will be REMOVED:
  abiword lubuntu-desktop
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 2 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
After this operation, 5,027 kB disk space will be freed.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] ^C
```

LXDE appears to *require* Abiword... even though Abiword is for *GNOME*. I don't really want Abiword (nor do I really want LXDE, but I think if I remove it, `lightdm` will break because it is fragile and wimpy, and then I will cry).

I could do `echo > /usr/bin/abiword`, but I'm afraid I might rupture LXDE, and this doesn't solve the problem that it's starting at login and there's no way to disable it (I've checked all the autostart settings; it isn't there).

Can I stop `abiword`, which is acting like a virus, from opening at boot?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Goto `Preferences > Default applications for LXDE > Autostart` and disable `Abiword`. Also regarding lubuntu-desktop, from `Synaptic:

> This metapackage package depends on all components of Lubuntu Desktop
>   system.
>
> It is also used to help ensure proper upgrades, but it can be safely
>   removed if you want to remove some applications installed by default.

As it is just a meta package, so, removing it will not harm your environment at all. If you are still worried about the meta packages, then goto [Ubuntu](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/MetaPackages):

> One of the handy features of apt (the packaging system used by Ubuntu) is the use of metapackages. These packages do not contain actual software, they simply depend on other packages to be installed. This setup allows entire sets of software to be installed by selecting only the appropriate metapackage. For example, an Ubuntu user can install the Kubuntu environment (KDE and all its associated programs) by selecting "kubuntu-desktop."

In there, it says that meta packages do not contain actual software. And in this list it says `lubuntu-desktop` is a meta package.

So, do not worry, go ahead and remove it.

Comment: thanks! I already tried to disable AbiWord in that menu, but I'll try again.

Comment: Is there a way to make a custom metapackage? One that includes everything except Abiword for example?

Comment: @user137 - This [answer](http://askubuntu.com/a/33417/119531) is what you are looking for.