# Azureus runs fine on latest java but its dependency check asks for dated version of JRE. How to tell Ubuntu to stop naggin me for "unmet dependency"?

Tags: java, dependencies, jre, vuze

So I force installed Vuze (and its dependency Azureus) via apt-get, and it is working fine on default-jre.

Even though the default-jre works as a dependency for Azureus (at least for my use-case scenario), the dependency check inside Azureus package demands an older and dated version of JRE, and I am being bombarded with unmet dependency message.

Each time I perform some apt-get operation, I get greeted with these:

```
You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these:
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 azureus : Depends: openjdk-7-jre but it is not installable or
                    openjdk-6-jre but it is not installable or
                    sun-java5-jre but it is not installable or
                    sun-java6-jre but it is not installable
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt-get -f install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

Edit: I do not want to "resolve" the dependency issue, because there is no dependency issue to resolve. The warning is erroneous because the dependency check inside Azureus is outdated.

Is there any way to tell Ubuntu to ignore the dependencies for this specific package?

Comment: And what happens if you do what it tells you to do? What does a `sudo apt-get -f install` do? Edit: It probably asks you to remove it. Fair point.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I resolve unmet dependencies after adding a PPA?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/140246/how-do-i-resolve-unmet-dependencies-after-adding-a-ppa)

Comment: I have read that thread you linked. That thread is about genuine unmet dependencies, mine is about a misunderstanding between packages. It is a very specific case. That being said, Azureus is not an available tag here. I don't have enough rep points to create a new tag. Can anyone create the tag so that in future people might have easier time finding Oli's answer when they search for the same issue?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to fake a package version installed?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/18192/how-to-fake-a-package-version-installed)

Comment: @Muru Those who do not know that package version can be faked will not search for that as a possible solution. Besides, this question has multiple answers. Faking package version is just one of those answers. You yourself edited the second answer.

Comment: @user140259 if dupes were only for things that people would search as a possible solution, I'd agree that would be relevant. And you'll note the time gap between this close vote and the edit. FWIW, I VTC'd in the review queue, where only the question and comments are seen, not answers.

Comment: @muru Thanks for the upvote. Sorry I am not trying to debate you, I am quite new here. The only guideline I read about dupes is this blog post :http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/04/handling-duplicate-questions/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have found another "arguably more appropriate" answer. This will give you the ability to edit out the wrong dependency inside the culprit package. Unlike the dummy package method, this will not affect the entire system.

You need `atool` (`sudo apt install dpkg-dev devscripts atool`) and `gdebi` (`dpkg` will do too, but I prefer `gdebi`)

`$pkg` = the name of the package that is causing issue.

```
apt-get download $pkg
mkdir pkg
atool -X pkg $pkg
vi pkg/DEBIAN/control
# [This is where you edit out the wrong dependencies]
rm -vf $pkg && dpkg-deb -b pkg $pkg
sudo gdebi $pkg
```

In my case, the line that I had to edit was :

```
Depends: openjdk-7-jre | openjdk-6-jre | sun-java5-jre | sun-java6-jre, libcommons-cli-java, liblog4j1.2-java, libswt-gtk-3-java, java-wrappers
```

Thank goes to sergall for [this solution](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu-tweak/+bug/1555706). Method has been personally verified by me.

Answer (score 2):

You can't tell Ubuntu to ignore the problem, but you can fake the [installation of a package by building a dummy version](https://askubuntu.com/questions/33413/how-to-create-a-meta-package-that-automatically-installs-other-packages). It's not *that* painful.

```
sudo apt install equivs
nano openjdk-7-jre
```

Paste in something like the following:

```
Section: misc
Priority: optional

Package: openjdk-7-jre
Description: Dummy package
```

And then run:

```
equivs-build openjdk-7-jre
sudo dpkg -i openjdk-7-jre_1.0_all.deb
```

Comment: Sorry I can't upvote because lack of rep points, but that was great answer. It instantly solved the issue. many thanks.

Comment: There should be a little tick underneath the score to mark this as the accepted answer.

Answer (score 0):

> `"Is there any way to tell Ubuntu to ignore the dependencies for this specific package?"`

No.

#### Why

If you need to talk to a french person, you need a translator - or learn french -, that will translate french words to english for you. You `depend` on that translator - or some other medium - to converse `properly` to that person.

Vuze has its own dependencies, which he `depends` on to work `properly`.

Also, Linux has much [better, faster, safer torrent clients](https://askubuntu.com/q/48546/36315) available by default.

**Links**

- [How do I resolve unmet dependencies after adding a PPA?](https://askubuntu.com/q/140246/36315)
- [List of GUI Based Torrent clients](https://askubuntu.com/q/48546/36315)

Comment: Oh come on. This is not Windows. We don't follow the norms here, we break them.