# Is it possible to set apt dependencies manually?

Tags: apt, package-management, dpkg, dependencies

First I install a program **A**, lets say `openssh-client`.

And, to work in my server, I would always need a program **B** alongside **A**, lets say `zip`, for example.

Is it possible to configure `apt` to set **B** (`zip`) as a "dependency" of **A** (`openssh-client`), in such a way that if I uninstall **A**, **B** will be automatically marked as `auto-installed`, and therefore will be removed next time `apt autoremove` is invoked; BUT as long as **A** is installed, **B** will not be uninstalled when running `apt autoremove`.

Note that I am not interested in setting **B** as "manually installed" because I would have to check it once **A** is uninstalled.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes you can.  It's called a metapackage.  It's essentially an empty package that pulls in all your "normal stuff" as a dependency.  Look at the *ubuntu-desktop package if you need a reference guide.  It doesn't really contain anything.  It's just a list of things to install.

So, you'ld want a "myjunk.deb" that pulls in both openssh-client and zip.  That way when you `apt-get remove myjunk`, it shows as openssh-client and zip are able to be removed.

- Credit to [Michael Dimmitt](https://askubuntu.com/users/684192/michael-dimmitt) for the [Ubuntu Community Help on Metapackages](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/MetaPackages)
- [How to create a meta-package that automatically installs other packages?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/33413/how-to-create-a-meta-package-that-automatically-installs-other-packages/)

Comment: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/MetaPackages