# How to create a meta-package?

Tags: package-management, debian, metapackages

I am trying to create a meta-package, which install all application that i will. Unfortunately i couldnot find any appropriate dockumentation about that. Does know someone how to do or where can i find documentation?
Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Meta package is an empty package that depends on other packages. So what is the real problem? If you know how to set dependencies, then what else do you need?

Comment: Here is [https://askubuntu.com/questions/33413/how-to-create-a-meta-package-that-automatically-installs-other-packages ] link explain for one package. I mean i have more apps. How should looks like a metapackage ?

Comment: Do the same, but add more in "depends". There are two depends there.

Comment: Not really this the link I shared too. What you mean add more depends? Each depends is the app that will be installed?

Comment: Exactly. Each depends is a package to be installed. In that example it installs `openssh-server` and `gedit`.

Comment: I did exact example on the link. But i got following error:"dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of my-metapackage:
 my-metapackage depends on openssh-server; however:
  Package openssh-server is not installed."

Comment: Actually I trying to install openssh-server. But it's telling thats missing.somehow it's strength

Comment: Run `sudo apt install -f` if you installed the package using `dpkg`.

Comment: As far as i understood, `sudo dpkg -i my_package.deb` is manual installation, which doesn't provide dependency installation. What will be proper installation of following package. `my-metapackage` ?

Comment: The proper installation will be `sudo dpkg -i my_package.deb && sudo apt install -f`, unless you create a repository and install using `apt`.

Comment: Those commands didnot work too. but i found another one which works. still thx sir. I addet as answer in duplicated question