# How to prevent ubuntu to install the package which is already installed manually by 'make install'?

Tags: package-management

I have manually installed ffmpeg which I built from source with GPU support,but when

```
sudo apt install kdenlive
```

System tells that

```
The following additional packages will be installed:
  ffmpeg
```

Would you please tell me how to make ubuntu to recognize the manually installed ffmpeg to stop installing another one?

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/questions/18192/how-to-fake-a-package-version-installed https://askubuntu.com/questions/33413/how-to-create-a-meta-package-that-automatically-installs-other-packages

Comment: `apt` has no idea what is installed by `make install` and is not supposed to know that.

Comment: Usually it doesn't matter because `make` installs in `/usr/share` which is used before the other version anyway. If you have two versions installed, the system will use the one in `/usr/share`

Answer (score 1):

Not with `apt`. Install the`equivs` package to generate meta-packages, and then use `dpkg` to install `kdenlive`. [Ubuntuforums on this](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=726317)

Comment: The `checkinstall` package can also be used for this.