# I installed a program by getting its source code, and then running `sudo make install`; how to make `apt-get` know about it?

Tags: apt, package-management, make

I installed program (call it, for example,`progA`) by building it from source code, and then finally calling `sudo make install` and `sudo ldconfig`.

However, it seems `apt-get` hasn't gotten the memo, because when installing `progB`, which depends on `progA`, `apt-get` recommends I also install `progA`. Why is this, and what could I do?

Comment: I think you have to install `progB` manually too...

Comment: **It can not be assumed that the 'custom' version you have created is the same as the package, that is a dependency.** A shortcut (not recommended) would be to install the real package, and then overwrite the binary with your 'special'. *As you have not been specific, I can provide no further advice.*

Comment: Just don't do this. Always keep software managed by your package management strictly separate from software you compile yourself.

Answer (score 56, accepted):

**TL;DR** `checkinstall` is your friend **;)**

```
sudo apt-get install checkinstall
```

---

After a installation with `sudo make install` your package manager knows absolutely nothing about this installation. But it knows all about a package with the same name in the Ubuntu repositories or in a PPA.

Use `sudo checkinstall` instead of `sudo make install` and use a higher version as the version in the repository to be sure, that your package manager accepts this version as correct dependency for `ProgB`.

---

**Further information:**

`checkinstall` is really nifty, since it follows what the `make install` command would do, in order to figure out how to build a package.

This means that if you install a program using `make install`, but then want to repent for your sins, all you have to do is `sudo checkinstall -D make install`, and that command will:

1. follow `make install` to figure out what it does
2. copy-cat `make install`, except in *.deb package form
3. install from the package (exactly as `make install` would have, given point 1)) except also let `apt-get` know about it, and thus overwrite all the files exactly where `make install` would have put them as long as you choose YES to include the files put by `make install` in the home directory in the package as well -- a couple of options during the `checkinstall` process will let you choose (obviously though, the choice is there so you can exercise it on a case-to-case basis)

**Bonus:** [you can also remove a package (call it `progA` again) installed using `make install` that odes not have `make uninstall` support](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14516283/3486684) by following the `checkinstall` process outlined so far, and then simply doing:

```
dpkg -r progA
```

Comment: Wow `checkinstall` -- THE WORLD needs to know about this!

Comment: I added some more detail to your answer, based on trying to implement it yesterday, and [the recommendations from this meta question](http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/14777/i-made-an-edit-to-a-question-adding-additional-details-i-learned-of-after-implem) -- please feel free to further edit it!

Comment: Which details do you mean?

Comment: Oh, I think they haven't appeared yet, because it is in edit review -- if you click on the link to the meta question, you will see what they are (originally, I had put them in the question body, but the recommendation was that I should put them in the accepted answer body).

Comment: The package documentation directory ./doc-pak does not exist. 
Should I create a default set of package docs?

Answer (score 13):

Three options:

1. create a fake package for `progA`: [How to fake a package version installed?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/18192/how-to-fake-a-package-version-installed) (there is an [extensive example for TeXlive)](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/95373/38080).
2. [create a package](https://debian-handbook.info/browse/stable/sect.building-first-package.html) for `progA`, easier if it has a `checkinstall` option: [How to trick apt dependencies?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/29918/how-to-trick-apt-dependencies)
3. Build also `progB` from sources.

Comment: 4. Uninstall the version of `progA` you compiled and install the `apt-get` version.  5. Install the `apt-get` package over the compiled version and hope for the best.

Answer (score 1):

I'd recommend using `uupdate` from `devscripts` and build the package like the original was build before.

Install required packages

```
$ sudo apt-get install build-essential devscripts
```

Download the the old package from official repository (will use `MediaWiki` as example) and the new tar-ball from upstream.

```
$ mkdir ~/Downloads/mediawiki
$ cd ~/Downloads/mediawiki
$ apt-get source mediawiki
$ wget https://releases.wikimedia.org/mediawiki/1.26/mediawiki-1.26.0.tar.gz
```

Run `uupdate` to create a new source folder from the upstream tar-ball and the old `debian/control`

```
$ cd mediawiki-1.19.14+dfsg   # depends on your Ubuntu version
$ uupdate ../mediawiki-1.26.0.tar.gz 1.26.0
$ cd ../mediawiki-1.26.0
```

Now you should check if you need to make changes to `debian/control` etc files. If you're done you can build the deb package and install it

```
$ dpkg-buildpackage -us -uc
$ cd ..
$ sudo dpkg -i *.deb
```