# How do I install sqlite3 ODBC drivers with unixODBC?

Tags: python, sqlite, sqlite3, odbc

According to the [unixODBC](http://www.unixodbc.org/) drivers page (straight out of the 90s), I should download the SQLite3 drivers from: http://www.ch-werner.de/sqliteodbc

The instructions for building `sqliteodbc` from the source code provided on that page is available here: http://www.ch-werner.de/sqliteodbc/html/index.html

According to that page, we should untar the source into a directory, and then run the following commands:

1) `./configure`
2) `make`
3) `make install`

However, when I run `./configure` in the directory, I get the following error:

`configure: error: No usable SQLite header/library on this system`

What should I do?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In order to deal with `configure: error: No usable SQLite header/library on this system`, one has to:

`sudo apt-get install libsqlite3-dev`

You might still get the following error after you do so:

`configure: error: ODBC header files and/or libraries not found`

In that case, do:

`sudo apt-get install unixodbc-dev unixodbc-bin unixodbc`

You might already have some of the packages listed there, but if you are getting the error, you are missing `unixodbc-dev`.

Alright, now you should:

1) `./configure && make` without issues

2) instead of `make install` check out the instructions here to learn all about `checkinstall`: [I installed a program by getting its source code, and then running `sudo make install`; how to make `apt-get` know about it?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/705369/i-installed-a-program-by-getting-its-source-code-and-then-running-sudo-make-in)

Now, reading further into the [instructions] provided for the `sqliteodbc` driver, we have to:

1) set up `odbcinst.ini` correctly

Open up the `odbcinst.ini` in an editor (you will probably need superuser abilities, and you will need to know where the file is -- usually it is in /etc, so we can do: `sudo gedit /etc/odbcinst.ini`), and add the following:

```
[SQLite3]
Description=SQLite ODBC Driver
Driver=/usr/local/lib/libsqlite3odbc.so
Setup=/usr/local/lib/libsqlite3odbc.so
Threading=4
```

Set up `Description` with any string you'd like, but make sure `Driver` and `Setup` have the right paths to the `*.so` provided by install the `sqliteodbc` driver. In order to figure out/confirm which `*.so` were provided: either `grep` or just open up `/usr/local/lib/` and check out which `*.so` files you have. For instance, according to the example in the instruction, you should point to `/usr/local/lib/libsqliteodbc.so`, but I only had `/usr/local/lib/libsqlite3odbc.so`. If you have both, you could make two entries like so:

```
[SQLite3]
Description=SQLite ODBC Driver
Driver=/usr/local/lib/libsqlite3odbc.so
Setup=/usr/local/lib/libsqlite3odbc.so
Threading=2

[SQLite]
Description=SQLite ODBC Driver
Driver=/usr/local/lib/libsqliteodbc.so
Setup=/usr/local/lib/libsqliteodbc.so
Threading=2
```

Also, make sure you choose some decent value for threading. For instance, if you have 8 cores, maybe `Threading=4` will make sense.

For the sake of step 2, I am going to set up things as:

```
[MYGOOFYSQLITE3DRIVERTAG]
Description=SQLite ODBC Driver
Driver=/usr/local/lib/libsqlite3odbc.so
Setup=/usr/local/lib/libsqlite3odbc.so
Threading=2
```

2) optional: setup a DNS in `~/.odbc.ini` --- just follow the instructions, but note that you can also use SQLite/3 DNS-less. For instance, using `pyodbc` and Python:

```
import pyodbc

connection_string = "Driver=MYGOOFYSQLITE3DRIVERTAG;Database=/path/to/database.db"
connection = pyodbc.connect(connection_string)
```

Note that for `Driver` key, I referred to the tag I gave the driver in `odbcinst.ini`. Maybe you want to be goofy, maybe you don't -- the point is that the key depends on what you set up, or what some other program automatically set up, so if you need to know what the Driver is called, look it up in `odbcinst.ini`.

Further details regarding what can go into the connection string can be found in the instructions for the `sqliteodbc` driver which we have referred to before.