# How to correct this error make: *** [install-recursive] Error 1

Tags: command-line

I am trying to install clicky which is part of click modular router.
When I run `sudo ./configure` command I get this output:

```
checking for a BSD-compatible install... /usr/bin/install -c
checking whether build environment is sane... yes
checking for a thread-safe mkdir -p... /bin/mkdir -p
checking for gawk... gawk
checking whether make sets $(MAKE)... yes
checking whether to enable maintainer-specific portions of Makefiles... no
checking for style of include used by make... GNU
checking for gcc... gcc
checking whether the C compiler works... yes
checking for C compiler default output file name... a.out
checking for suffix of executables... 
checking whether we are cross compiling... no
checking for suffix of object files... o
checking whether we are using the GNU C compiler... yes
checking whether gcc accepts -g... yes
checking for gcc option to accept ISO C89... none needed
checking dependency style of gcc... gcc3
checking for library containing strerror... none required
checking whether make sets $(MAKE)... (cached) yes
checking for gcc... (cached) gcc
checking whether we are using the GNU C compiler... (cached) yes
checking whether gcc accepts -g... (cached) yes
checking for gcc option to accept ISO C89... (cached) none needed
checking dependency style of gcc... (cached) gcc3
checking for gcc... (cached) gcc
checking whether we are using the GNU C compiler... (cached) yes
checking whether gcc accepts -g... (cached) yes
checking for gcc option to accept ISO C89... (cached) none needed
checking dependency style of gcc... (cached) gcc3
checking how to run the C preprocessor... gcc -E
checking for g++... g++
checking whether we are using the GNU C++ compiler... yes
checking whether g++ accepts -g... yes
checking dependency style of g++... gcc3
checking how to run the C++ preprocessor... g++ -E
checking for pkg-config... /usr/bin/pkg-config
checking pkg-config is at least version 0.9.0... yes
checking for PACKAGE... yes
configure: creating ./config.status
config.status: creating Makefile
config.status: creating src/Makefile
config.status: creating config.h
config.status: config.h is unchanged
config.status: executing depfiles commands
```

Then with command `sudo make install` I get this output and error:

```
Making install in src
make[1]: Entering directory `/home/delila/click/apps/clicky/src'
gcc -W -Wall -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I..  -DPACKAGE_DATA_DIR=\""/usr/local/share"\" -DPACKAGE_LOCALE_DIR=\""/usr/local//locale"\" -pthread -D_REENTRANT -I/usr/include/gtk-2.0 -I/usr/lib/gtk-2.0/include -I/usr/include/atk-1.0 -I/usr/include/cairo -I/usr/include/pango-1.0 -I/usr/include/gio-unix-2.0/ -I/usr/include/glib-2.0 -I/usr/lib/glib-2.0/include -I/usr/include/pixman-1 -I/usr/include/freetype2 -I/usr/include/directfb -I/usr/include/libpng12 `/usr/local/bin/click-buildtool --toolcflags`   -g -O2 -MT support.o -MD -MP -MF .deps/support.Tpo -c -o support.o support.c
support.c: In function ‘create_pixmap’:
support.c:77: warning: unused parameter ‘widget’
mv -f .deps/support.Tpo .deps/support.Po
g++ -W -Wall -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I..  -DPACKAGE_DATA_DIR=\""/usr/local/share"\" -DPACKAGE_LOCALE_DIR=\""/usr/local//locale"\" -pthread -D_REENTRANT -I/usr/include/gtk-2.0 -I/usr/lib/gtk-2.0/include -I/usr/include/atk-1.0 -I/usr/include/cairo -I/usr/include/pango-1.0 -I/usr/include/gio-unix-2.0/ -I/usr/include/glib-2.0 -I/usr/lib/glib-2.0/include -I/usr/include/pixman-1 -I/usr/include/freetype2 -I/usr/include/directfb -I/usr/include/libpng12 `/usr/local/bin/click-buildtool --toolcflags`   -g -O2 -MT gathererror.o -MD -MP -MF .deps/gathererror.Tpo -c -o gathererror.o gathererror.cc
mv -f .deps/gathererror.Tpo .deps/gathererror.Po
g++ -W -Wall -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I..  -DPACKAGE_DATA_DIR=\""/usr/local/share"\" -DPACKAGE_LOCALE_DIR=\""/usr/local//locale"\" -pthread -D_REENTRANT -I/usr/include/gtk-2.0 -I/usr/lib/gtk-2.0/include -I/usr/include/atk-1.0 -I/usr/include/cairo -I/usr/include/pango-1.0 -I/usr/include/gio-unix-2.0/ -I/usr/include/glib-2.0 -I/usr/lib/glib-2.0/include -I/usr/include/pixman-1 -I/usr/include/freetype2 -I/usr/include/directfb -I/usr/include/libpng12 `/usr/local/bin/click-buildtool --toolcflags`   -g -O2 -MT permstr.o -MD -MP -MF .deps/permstr.Tpo -c -o permstr.o permstr.cc
mv -f .deps/permstr.Tpo .deps/permstr.Po
g++ -W -Wall -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I..  -DPACKAGE_DATA_DIR=\""/usr/local/share"\" -DPACKAGE_LOCALE_DIR=\""/usr/local//locale"\" -pthread -D_REENTRANT -I/usr/include/gtk-2.0 -I/usr/lib/gtk-2.0/include -I/usr/include/atk-1.0 -I/usr/include/cairo -I/usr/include/pango-1.0 -I/usr/include/gio-unix-2.0/ -I/usr/include/glib-2.0 -I/usr/lib/glib-2.0/include -I/usr/include/pixman-1 -I/usr/include/freetype2 -I/usr/include/directfb -I/usr/include/libpng12 `/usr/local/bin/click-buildtool --toolcflags`   -g -O2 -MT scopechain.o -MD -MP -MF .deps/scopechain.Tpo -c -o scopechain.o scopechain.cc
mv -f .deps/scopechain.Tpo .deps/scopechain.Po
g++ -W -Wall -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I..  -DPACKAGE_DATA_DIR=\""/usr/local/share"\" -DPACKAGE_LOCALE_DIR=\""/usr/local//locale"\" -pthread -D_REENTRANT -I/usr/include/gtk-2.0 -I/usr/lib/gtk-2.0/include -I/usr/include/atk-1.0 -I/usr/include/cairo -I/usr/include/pango-1.0 -I/usr/include/gio-unix-2.0/ -I/usr/include/glib-2.0 -I/usr/lib/glib-2.0/include -I/usr/include/pixman-1 -I/usr/include/freetype2 -I/usr/include/directfb -I/usr/include/libpng12 `/usr/local/bin/click-buildtool --toolcflags`   -g -O2 -MT crouter.o -MD -MP -MF .deps/crouter.Tpo -c -o crouter.o crouter.cc
mv -f .deps/crouter.Tpo .deps/crouter.Po
g++ -W -Wall -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I..  -DPACKAGE_DATA_DIR=\""/usr/local/share"\" -DPACKAGE_LOCALE_DIR=\""/usr/local//locale"\" -pthread -D_REENTRANT -I/usr/include/gtk-2.0 -I/usr/lib/gtk-2.0/include -I/usr/include/atk-1.0 -I/usr/include/cairo -I/usr/include/pango-1.0 -I/usr/include/gio-unix-2.0/ -I/usr/include/glib-2.0 -I/usr/lib/glib-2.0/include -I/usr/include/pixman-1 -I/usr/include/freetype2 -I/usr/include/directfb -I/usr/include/libpng12 `/usr/local/bin/click-buildtool --toolcflags`   -g -O2 -MT cdriver.o -MD -MP -MF .deps/cdriver.Tpo -c -o cdriver.o cdriver.cc
mv -f .deps/cdriver.Tpo .deps/cdriver.Po
g++ -W -Wall -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I..  -DPACKAGE_DATA_DIR=\""/usr/local/share"\" -DPACKAGE_LOCALE_DIR=\""/usr/local//locale"\" -pthread -D_REENTRANT -I/usr/include/gtk-2.0 -I/usr/lib/gtk-2.0/include -I/usr/include/atk-1.0 -I/usr/include/cairo -I/usr/include/pango-1.0 -I/usr/include/gio-unix-2.0/ -I/usr/include/glib-2.0 -I/usr/lib/glib-2.0/include -I/usr/include/pixman-1 -I/usr/include/freetype2 -I/usr/include/directfb -I/usr/include/libpng12 `/usr/local/bin/click-buildtool --toolcflags`   -g -O2 -MT hvalues.o -MD -MP -MF .deps/hvalues.Tpo -c -o hvalues.o hvalues.cc
mv -f .deps/hvalues.Tpo .deps/hvalues.Po
g++ -W -Wall -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I..  -DPACKAGE_DATA_DIR=\""/usr/local/share"\" -DPACKAGE_LOCALE_DIR=\""/usr/local//locale"\" -pthread -D_REENTRANT -I/usr/include/gtk-2.0 -I/usr/lib/gtk-2.0/include -I/usr/include/atk-1.0 -I/usr/include/cairo -I/usr/include/pango-1.0 -I/usr/include/gio-unix-2.0/ -I/usr/include/glib-2.0 -I/usr/lib/glib-2.0/include -I/usr/include/pixman-1 -I/usr/include/freetype2 -I/usr/include/directfb -I/usr/include/libpng12 `/usr/local/bin/click-buildtool --toolcflags`   -g -O2 -MT dstyle.o -MD -MP -MF .deps/dstyle.Tpo -c -o dstyle.o dstyle.cc
mv -f .deps/dstyle.Tpo .deps/dstyle.Po
g++ -W -Wall -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I..  -DPACKAGE_DATA_DIR=\""/usr/local/share"\" -DPACKAGE_LOCALE_DIR=\""/usr/local//locale"\" -pthread -D_REENTRANT -I/usr/include/gtk-2.0 -I/usr/lib/gtk-2.0/include -I/usr/include/atk-1.0 -I/usr/include/cairo -I/usr/include/pango-1.0 -I/usr/include/gio-unix-2.0/ -I/usr/include/glib-2.0 -I/usr/lib/glib-2.0/include -I/usr/include/pixman-1 -I/usr/include/freetype2 -I/usr/include/directfb -I/usr/include/libpng12 `/usr/local/bin/click-buildtool --toolcflags`   -g -O2 -MT wmain.o -MD -MP -MF .deps/wmain.Tpo -c -o wmain.o wmain.cc
mv -f .deps/wmain.Tpo .deps/wmain.Po
g++ -W -Wall -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I..  -DPACKAGE_DATA_DIR=\""/usr/local/share"\" -DPACKAGE_LOCALE_DIR=\""/usr/local//locale"\" -pthread -D_REENTRANT -I/usr/include/gtk-2.0 -I/usr/lib/gtk-2.0/include -I/usr/include/atk-1.0 -I/usr/include/cairo -I/usr/include/pango-1.0 -I/usr/include/gio-unix-2.0/ -I/usr/include/glib-2.0 -I/usr/lib/glib-2.0/include -I/usr/include/pixman-1 -I/usr/include/freetype2 -I/usr/include/directfb -I/usr/include/libpng12 `/usr/local/bin/click-buildtool --toolcflags`   -g -O2 -MT dialogs.o -MD -MP -MF .deps/dialogs.Tpo -c -o dialogs.o dialogs.cc
dialogs.cc: In member function ‘void clicky::wmain::on_export_diagram()’:
dialogs.cc:485: error: ‘gtk_combo_box_text_new’ was not declared in this scope
dialogs.cc:486: error: ‘GTK_COMBO_BOX_TEXT’ was not declared in this scope
dialogs.cc:486: error: ‘gtk_combo_box_text_append_text’ was not declared in this scope
make[1]: *** [dialogs.o] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/delila/click/apps/clicky/src'
make: *** [install-recursive] Error 1
```

Anyone knows how to fix this???

Following another steps with checkinstall I got this error

```
    delila@delila:~/src/click-2.0.1/apps/clicky$ sudo checkinstall

    checkinstall 1.6.1, Copyright 2002 Felipe Eduardo Sanchez Diaz Duran
               This software is released under the GNU GPL.



    *****************************************
    **** Debian package creation selected ***
    *****************************************

    *** Warning: The package version "0.1
    0.1
    0.1
    0.1
    0.1" is not a
    *** Warning: debian policy compliant one. Please specify an alternate one


    This package will be built according to these values: 

    0 -  Maintainer: [ root@delila ]
    1 -  Summary: [ Package created with checkinstall 1.6.1 ]
    2 -  Name:    [ clicky ]
    3 -  Version: [  ]
    4 -  Release: [ 1 ]
    5 -  License: [ GPL ]
    6 -  Group:   [ checkinstall ]
    7 -  Architecture: [ amd64 ]
    8 -  Source location: [ clicky ]
    9 -  Alternate source location: [  ]
    10 - Requires: [  ]
    11 - Provides: [ clicky ]

    Enter a number to change any of them or press ENTER to continue: 3
    Enter new version: 
    >> 0.1-1 0

    *** Warning: The package version "0.1-1 0" is not a
    *** Warning: debian policy compliant one. Please specify an alternate one


    This package will be built according to these values: 

    0 -  Maintainer: [ root@delila ]
    1 -  Summary: [ Package created with checkinstall 1.6.1 ]
    2 -  Name:    [ clicky ]
    3 -  Version: [  ]
    4 -  Release: [ 1 ]
    5 -  License: [ GPL ]
    6 -  Group:   [ checkinstall ]
    7 -  Architecture: [ amd64 ]
    8 -  Source location: [ clicky ]
    9 -  Alternate source location: [  ]
    10 - Requires: [  ]
    11 - Provides: [ clicky ]

    Enter a number to change any of them or press ENTER to continue:
Installing with make...Installing with install...

========================= Installation results ===========================
Making install in src
make[1]: Entering directory `/home/delila/src/click-2.0.1/apps/clicky/src'
make[2]: Entering directory `/home/delila/src/click-2.0.1/apps/clicky/src'
test -z "/usr/local/bin" || /bin/mkdir -p "/usr/local/bin"
  /usr/bin/install -c clicky '/usr/local/bin'
make[2]: Nothing to be done for `install-data-am'.
make[2]: Leaving directory `/home/delila/src/click-2.0.1/apps/clicky/src'
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/delila/src/click-2.0.1/apps/clicky/src'
make[1]: Entering directory `/home/delila/src/click-2.0.1/apps/clicky'
make[2]: Entering directory `/home/delila/src/click-2.0.1/apps/clicky'
make[2]: Nothing to be done for `install-exec-am'.
test -z "/usr/local/share/clicky" || /bin/mkdir -p "/usr/local/share/clicky"
 /usr/bin/install -c -m 644 images/throbber.gif clicky.gtkrc '/usr/local/share/clicky'
make[2]: Leaving directory `/home/delila/src/click-2.0.1/apps/clicky'
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/delila/src/click-2.0.1/apps/clicky'

======================== Installation successful ==========================

Copying documentation directory...
./
./AUTHORS
./NEWS
./README
grep: /var/tmp/tmp.L6QhOx8VdZ/newfile: No such file or directory

Copying files to the temporary directory...OK

Stripping ELF binaries and libraries...OK

Compressing man pages...OK

Building file list...OK

Building Debian package... FAILED!

*** Failed to build the package

Do you want to see the log file?  [y]: y

dpkg-deb: parse error, in file '/var/tmp/tmp.L6QhOx8VdZ/package/DEBIAN/control' near line 10 package 'clicky':
 empty value for version
```

Thank you!

Comment: This is a bug in source packages. Please report to clicky.

Comment: @frlan There is no bug. Read my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The installation works as expected but first you have to install `click`.

1. Install `checkinstall`

   ```
   sudo apt-get install checkinstall
   ```

   Why? Read [this](https://askubuntu.com/a/705380/367165).
2. Download the current release `click-2.0.1`

   ```
   wget http://www.read.cs.ucla.edu/click/click-2.0.1.tar.gz
   ```
3. Extract

   ```
   mkdir -p ~/src
   tar xf click-2.0.1.tar.gz -C ~/src
   ```
4. Configure and install `click`, `make` isn't necessary

   ```
   cd ~/src/click-2.0.1
   ./configure
   sudo checkinstall
   ```
5. Check `click`

   ```
   % apt-cache policy click
   click:
     Installed: 2.0.1-1
     Candidate: 2.0.1-1
     Version table:
    *** 2.0.1-1 0
           100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
        0.4.39.1+15.10.20150702-0ubuntu2 0
           500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ wily/main amd64 Packages
   ```
6. Configure and install `clicky` and here also, no `make` necessary

   ```
   cd ~/src/click-2.0.1/apps/clicky
   autoreconf -i
   ./configure
   sudo checkinstall
   ```

   You have to change the version number after run `checkinstall`
7. Check `clicky`

   ```
   % apt-cache policy clicky 
   clicky:
     Installed: 0.1-1
     Candidate: 0.1-1
     Version table:
    *** 0.1-1 0
           100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
   ```
8. Run `clicky`

   [image]

Comment: I have followed your steps and everything is ok until I try to install clicky with command sudo checkinstall. I edited my question so you can see what type of error I get. Thank you

Comment: Run `sudo checkinstall` again and give the package a version. To do that, press `3` and type `0.1` Your version number isn't a valid version. That's all :)