# How to upgrade poppler-utils to latest version?

Tags: apt, upgrade, software-installation, poppler

My system has `poppler-utils v0.24.5`. From the [official site](http://poppler.freedesktop.org/) I found that the latest version is `0.40.0`.

I tried to update it using following command

`sudo apt-get install --only-upgrade poppler-utils`

but it doesn't upgrade and show following message.

`poppler-utils is already the newest version.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 14 not upgraded.`

Can anybody please help me to upgrade to latest version?

Comment: Similarly important as to why `apt-get install` didn't update the software: [Why don't the Ubuntu repositories have the latest versions of software?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/151283/why-dont-the-ubuntu-repositories-have-the-latest-versions-of-software)

Comment: See also: [How to install the latest version of poppler?](https://askubuntu.com/q/781552/327339). That Q&A seems to be the most-visited and active.

Comment: I added detailed instructions here too: [How to install/upgrade to the latest version of Poppler/`pdftoppm` (version 22.11.0 at the time of this writing) on Linux Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/a/1439020/327339)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is because Ubuntu focuses on stability, not bleeding edge packages, this means that the software in the repositories can be outdated and you must build it from source yourself.

First remove the current installed version

```
sudo apt-get purge poppler-utils
```

Install the required build tools

```
sudo apt-get install build-essential checkinstall
```

Run these commands to build and install

```
wget --directory-prefix=~ poppler.freedesktop.org/poppler-0.40.0.tar.xz
tar -xvzf ~/poppler-0.40.0.tar.xz
cd ~/poppler-0.40.0
./configure
make
sudo checkinstall
```

Now `poppler-0.40.0` is installed on your computer.

Comment: Relevant: http://askubuntu.com/a/705380/367165

Comment: @markkirby : Another useful answer from you ! :)

Comment: If you run the wget command from your home directory, you may end up with a new directory `/home/username/\~` . I'm not sure what caused this though. It's also not gzip compression, so the `-z` seems unnecessary.

Comment: I think its 'build-essential' rather than 'build-essentials' in the install line, right?

Comment: @ohnoplus Yes it should, well spotted.

Comment: Currently, the latest version that can be installed on Kubuntu 14.04 without a newer version of cmake is poppler-0.59.0. On my system, the `tar` command works only without the `-z` switch.