# How to replace PulseAudio package with self-compiled one?

Tags: apt, pulseaudio

So I want to replace PulseAudio 8 on my Ubuntu 16.04 with PulseAudio 11 (because the latter has better support for bluetooth headsets).

I've managed to compile PulseAudio 11 from source, and everything seems to work fine after I do `sudo make install`, however, every once in a while Ubuntu Software Updater upgrades PulseAudio and rolls me back to version 8.

I cannot just uninstall the standard PulseAudio package, because there's a ton of packages that depend on it, as well as a bunch of libraries that PulseAudio itself needs (and which Ubuntu's package manager wants to remove when their dependency disappears).

Is there a "proper" way of doing this, that plays nicely with packages?

Comment: Or [I installed a program by getting its source code, and then running `sudo make install`; how to make `apt-get` know about it?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/705369/i-installed-a-program-by-getting-its-source-code-and-then-running-sudo-make-in/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At first, I tried [`checkinstall`](https://askubuntu.com/a/705380/780445), but it produced a package without any dependencies, so I still had that problem of package manager uninstalling libraries that PulseAudio depends upon.

Instead, I followed [this suggestion](https://askubuntu.com/a/705698/780445) and got a package that was much closer to the original.  Have not had any problems with it ...so far.