# Package from APT repo, dependencies installed manually (in /usr/local...); how to tell APT?

Tags: apt

I had installed a the TeX editor `kile` from the official Ubuntu PPA. It came together with a bunch of dependencies, TeXlive among them. The provided TeXlive version however is from 2015 and thus quite old, buggy and outdated. I removed all texlive* components manually by means of `dpkg -r --force-all` and reinstalled a more recent version of texlive via the official texlive installer (install-tl). Works like a charm so far.

Other than `apt`, which now insists on reinstalling the old texlive because of that unsatisfied dependency. How can I tell `apt` to permanently ignore that missing dependency in the future and behave as if it were installed (which it actually is, just not through `apt`)?

Comment: Or [I installed a program by getting its source code, and then running `sudo make install`; how to make `apt-get` know about it?](https://askubuntu.com/q/705369/158442)

Comment: They all recommend installing something like checkinstall... Through apt, which doesn't work because of the missing dependencies that I have to solve before I can install something...

Comment: In that case, I'd suggest removing kile, install equivs/checkinstall, faking the dependency, then reinstalling kile.