# how to include manually installed software in apt dependency checks

Tags: apt

I have installed python-3.7.0 from source.  I'm trying to install glib2.0-dev using `sudo apt install glib2.0-dev`.  It tries to install python3.6-minimal as a needed dependency.  How do I point at the 3.7 install?  Does it install 3.6 to use it just for the install and then it can later be removed?

Comment: Use `checkinstall` (provided by the 'checkinstall' package) during the build. After the build is too late. Note that you should NEVER alter or remove the system-provided version of Python and Python3 (exclusively Py3 in 18.04 and newer), as critical system components --like the package manager-- depend upon that specific version. If you have already done so, then backup your data and reinstall.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [I installed a program by getting its source code, and then running \`sudo make install\`; how to make \`apt-get\` know about it?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/705369/i-installed-a-program-by-getting-its-source-code-and-then-running-sudo-make-in)